# how do i do role wise react routing with auth?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I followed the protected routing in React router 4 examples, I signed in using that protected method. The next step is I want to move with role based routing, example user can go with /user and admin can go with /admin page.

```
class Routing extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

In that component is common component for the user/admin, after check the user/admin role in that Component, I want to redirect as user if its a user or it will be admin.

Even also i want to handle /user router and /admin router also globally.

This is what I tried, but seems its not working...

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="">
          <h1>Payement</h1>
        </header>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/user' component={User} />
          <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin} />
          {
            localStorage.getItem('role') === 'user' &&
            <Redirect to={'/user'} />
          }
          {
            localStorage.getItem('role') === 'admin' &&
            <Redirect to={'/admin'} />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why it does not work ? What's the current behavior/error ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini it loads until the app component only, the user component not loading..

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini no errors..

Comment: mhmh I don't see a <Switch /> wrapping your routes

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini . switch is wrapping in Routing component, but also tried with in the app component too, still no response and no errors.

Comment: can you post a working snippet on stackblitz ?

Comment: my overall code :   https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zutjka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work after all the routes in a single file, in Routing Component.

```
class Routing extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={App} />
                <PrivateRoute path='/user' component={User} />
                <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={Admin} />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
```

and removed the route in app.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={App} />
```

with

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={App} />
```

**The problem**

This is due to the route not be taken in cosideration with `exact` prop.
`exact` routes will be taken in consideration only when the routes matches perfectly.

Obviously to login as *Admin* you have to modify your Login component, actually logging only as *User*.

```
login = () => {

          localStorage.setItem('role', this.uname.value);
          fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
              this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
            });
        };
```

**Other notes**

Additionally, if I can give my 2 cents, avoid to use *refs* unless is necessary.

The right way to retrieve an input value is like

```
 <input onChange={(event) =>  this.setState({loginvalue: event.target.value})} />
```

Then retrieve it from state:

```
this.state.loginvalue
```

Comment: i just checking if any will works i will change for user and admin. Thanks for the input value updates..